# How do I push an object with two parameters in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been following the [angular tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial, and I'm doing the `Http` section, using the `InMemoryDBService`. I've been trying to play with the code, and I want to know how I can push an object with two parameters. 
I want to push an object with its name and the year (currently hard coded as 2017 in the hero.component.ts) and add it to the list.

**in-memory-data.service.ts**

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Chuck Norris', year: 2019 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Donald Duck', year: 2019 },
      { id: 3, name: 'Ash Catchem', year: 2019 },
      { id: 4, name: 'Morgan Freeman', year: 2019 },
      { id: 5, name: 'Luke Skywalker', year: 2019 },
      { id: 6, name: 'Bob Ross', year: 2018 },
      { id: 7, name: 'Sherlock Homes', year: 2018 },
      { id: 8, name: 'Bugs Bunny', year: 2018 },
      { id: 9, name: 'Edgar Poe', year: 2018 },
      { id: 10, name: 'Barack Obama', year: 2018 }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

**hero.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Hero } from './hero';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
  }

  /** POST: add a new hero to the server */
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions);
}
```

}

**hero.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { Hero } from '../hero';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[];
  year: number = 2017;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
      });
    }

}
```

**hero.component.html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}} {{hero.year}}
  </div>
<br>
  <div>
    <label>Hero name:
      <input #heroName />
    </label>
    <!-- (click) passes input value to add() and then clears the input -->
    <button (click)="add(heroName.value); heroName.value=''">
      add
    </button>
  </div>
```

So, I know I have to add a parameter to the html component, such as: `<button (click)="add(heroName.value, year); heroName.value=''">` and then I also have to add a parameter inside of the components.ts and service.ts, but I'm unsure on exactly how to change this suit my needs, here is my best attempt:

```
  add(name: string, year): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name, year } as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
      });
    }
```

However, it doesn't add the year after hitting the add button, and this is where I need some help.

Comment: have you had a chance to review the answer?

Comment: @PatricioVargas I did look at it, but it didn't quite fit the answer I was looking for. I eventually figured it out and posted the answer.

Comment: Cool! I saw your answer. Glad you solved it. Just updated the answer saying you figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra parameter to the function, and add another parameter to the function the button emits.

**hero.component.ts**

```
add(name: string, year: number): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name, year } as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
      });
    }
```

**hero.component.html**

```
<button (click)="add(heroName.value, year); heroName.value=''">
      add
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a class that looks like this:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  year: number;
}
```

if you want to create a new Object of type hero then push it to your array.

```
add(name: string, year: number) {
   const hero = new Hero (this.heroes.length++, name, year);
   //the rest of your code 
   this.getHeroes(); //this will pull the updated list of heroes  
}
```

Where the first argument I'm passing is the length of the array + 1 to give it and Id dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<button (click)="add(heroName.value, year); heroName.value=''">
```

To this

```
<button (click)="add(heroName.value, hero.year); heroName.value=''">
```

"year" doesnt reference anything, while "hero.year" actually accesses the individual element of the ngFor = "let hero of heroes".